# Prime dividing sum of divisors

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, factoring, divisor-counting-function

The sum of divisors function is given by

$$\sigma(n)=\prod_{i=1}^r\frac{p_i^{a_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}=\prod_{i=1}^r(1+p_i+p_i^2+\cdots+{p_i}^{a_i})$$ with $$n=\prod_{i=1}^r{p_i}^{a_i}$$

I call each term in the sigma product formula a factor $f(p_i, a_i)$. For $p$ to divide $\sigma(n)$, it must divide at least one of the factors. The rest of the factors can then be any values.

My questions:

1. When will $f(p_m, a_m)=f(p_n, a_n)$? I did a small test with $p<100,a\le10$ and found $f(5,2) = f(2,4) = 31$.
2. I believe finding all $n$ such that $p|\sigma(n)$ can be achieved by finding $p|f(p_i,a_i)$ and using all multiples $k \cdot f(p_i,a_i)$ with $p_i \nmid k$. I'm worried that I might get duplicate multiples of $k_m \cdot f(p_m,a_m) = k_n \cdot f(p_n,a_n)$, as with the immediate case $2f(3,1)=f(7,1)=8$. Can I find all $n$ using my method without duplicates?

Comment: You probably mean to call each term in the product a factor $f(p_i,a_i)$  The most common case for 1 will probably be when there are odd primes $p,q$ with $p+1=q^3+q^2+q+1$ because the left side is even, so you need the $q^3$ term to make the right even as well.  This would be $f(p,1)=f(q,3)$

Comment: @RossMillikan It is not possible since $p$ would become $q^3+q^2+q$.

Comment: Finding all solutions of $${p^r-1\over p-1}={q^s-1\over q-1}$$ is a notorious unsolved problem in Number Theory. I don't have Guy's book, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, handy, but I know it's discussed there.

Comment: @qwr, Would you please explain why you want to use multiples of $f(p_i, a_i)$ in question 2? Also, why are you worried about having duplicates?

Comment: @i707107 Multiples lead to more values of $n$ that would not be found with just one factor. Also having duplicates makes it difficult to count the number of solutions.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to find at the end. Do you want to find all $n$ satisfying $p|\sigma(n)$ or not? Also, do you want to count the number of solutions in which equation?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would help. It seems that you want to find $n$ satisfying $p|\sigma(n)$ for some prime $p$. The following is easy to see from the factorization of $\sigma(n)$:
$$
p|\sigma(n) \ \Longleftrightarrow p|\frac{q^{e+1}-1}{q-1}
$$
for at least one prime divisor $q|n$ with $q^e||n$.

There are two cases that this can happen:

**Case 1: $p|q-1$**

If $p|q-1$ then $\frac{q^{e+1}-1}{q-1} \equiv e+1 \ \mathrm{mod} \ p$. Then it follows that $p|e+1$.

**Case 2: $p\nmid q-1$**

If $p\nmid q-1$ then $p|q^{e+1}-1$. This means that $\mathrm{ord}_p(q) |e+1$.

Comment: I don't see how this helps me answer my second question.

Comment: If you are concerned about finding $n$ such that $p|\sigma(n)$, I think that you only need to find some $q|n$ with the property that I wrote.

Comment: why does it have to be like this, why can't p divide both?