# Find solution set of Diophantine equation: $\frac{a^b-1}{a-1}=\frac{c^d-1}{c-1}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

After reading up on [Catalan's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), a related equation piqued my interest:

Let $a>c>1$ and $b,d>2$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. I am looking for integer solutions to
$$
\frac{a^b-1}{a-1}=\frac{c^d-1}{c-1}.
$$
By some trial and error (educated guessing), I found the solution
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{5^3-1}{5-1}&=\frac{2^5-1}{2-1}\\
\frac{125-1}{4}&=\frac{31}{1}\\
\frac{125-1}{4}&=\frac{31}{1}\\
31&=31
\end{align*}$$

Is there a technique to find the whole solution set? I have not been successful in finding any patterns whatsoever.

Comment: FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Ba%5Eb-1%7D%7Ba-1%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7Bc%5Ed-1%7D%7Bc-1%7D%24&p=1), I found the related AoPS threads [Dio Equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1452835p8343644), [Hard Diophantine Equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1300874p6929271) and [(a^x-1)/(a - 1)=(b^y -1)/(b - 1) two solution in N, means a,b coprime](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1846594p12436720).

Comment: Ah, so it seems other have looked at this equation as well. However, there is really nothing of substance there. :(

Comment: Also, [Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886679/prime-dividing-sum-of-divisors?noredirect=1#comment3868488_1886679) states "Finding all solutions of $$\frac{p^r - 1}{p -1} = \frac{q^s - 1}{q -1}$$ is a notorious unsolved problem in Number Theory. I don't have Guy's book, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, handy, but I know it's discussed there." Note that $p$ and $q$ are primes, I believe both meant to be odd.

Comment: I realize there's not much there in the AoPS threads, but I wanted you to be aware of them nonetheless. Nonetheless, message #$6$ of [Hard Diophantine Equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1300874p6929271) says "This paper: http://msp.org/pjm/2002/207-1/pjm-v207-n1-p04-s.pdf". I have only read the summary, but it basically deals with your question (it has a title of "ON THE DIOPHANTINE EQUATION $\frac{x^m - 1}{x - 1} = \frac{y^n - 1}{y - 1}$"), so I believe you should find it interesting, and perhaps also useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who commented! I'll go ahead and answer my own question. I found a wikipedia page on this exact problem, where it is labelled the [Goormaghtigh conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goormaghtigh_conjecture), and is listed under the wiki page of unsolved problems in number theory. So it seems that if anyone knew how to solve this equation that would be mighty impressive.

Also, the [paper](https://msp.org/pjm/2002/207-1/pjm-v207-n1-p04-s.pdf) that John Omielan linked in the comments seems to be the best resource on this problem.